# Retrieving data from siblings to node that match

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, siblings

I'm iterating through a xml doc with SimpleXML. I have an array ($ids) with id's and I'm checking whether there's a match or not in the XML (Worksheet/Table/Row/Cell/Data). If it's a match I want to be able to get to the data from the following two siblings, but I can't figure out how.

**from the php:**

```
// $ids <---- array('8', '53', '38')

foreach ($thePositions->Worksheet->Table->Row as $row) {

    if($row->Cell->Data == true) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
            foreach($row->Cell->Data as $data) {

                if ($data == $ids[$i]) {
                    echo 'match!';

                    /* 
                       Tried $siblings = $data->xpath('preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*');
                       but doesn't seem to work in this case.
                    */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**the xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <LastAuthor>Herpa Derp </LastAuthor>
  <Created>2012-09-25T13:44:01Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2012-09-25T13:48:24Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>14.0</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>14060</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>25040</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>25540</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>4100</WindowTopY>
  <Date1904/>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Font ss:FontName="Courier" ss:Color="#000000"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Workbook1.csv">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="79" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="65" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:Index="2" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="43"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="220"/>
   <Row ss:Index="6">
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="String">id</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">latitude</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">longitude</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="Number">8</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">57.4999</Data></Cell>    // to be saved to $latutude
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">15.8280</Data></Cell>    // to be saved to $longitude
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="Number">38</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">56.5659</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">16.1380</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Comment: How about the `XML` namespace definition

Comment: What does not work? Too many results? No results? And you can run it completely in XPath like `//Row[Cell/Data[. = '8' or . = '53' or . = '38']]/following-sibling::*[position() <= 2]` if you want the 2 next siblings

Comment: @BeniBela why is that a comment and not an answer if it solves the posed problem?

Comment: @IMSoP: Because we don't know what exactly his problem is. He said, he wants the following sibling, but the comment also reads preceding siblings... And it would not work, if there are namespace issues..

Comment: @BeniBela The question includes a fairly clear example, against which you could test your code, and seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @IMSoP: well, if you think so, i can also post it...

Comment: holyredbeard, You forgot to tell us what exact result you want to be produced? It wouldnt be useful to have a result like "MatchMatch" because this doesn't give us even one bit of information -- what of the "ids" was matched and which one wasn't matched. Please, edit the question and explain this well, so that people will not have to guess. Of course, your obvious and most pressing problem is that the source XML document is in a default namespace and that "SimpleXML" isn't a compliant XPath engine, therefore it is possible that a correct XPath solution might not be usable with SimpleXML.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm 90% sure this problem has absolutely nothing to do with namespaces or XPath compliance. I'm still not sure why people think the question is under-specified; it seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @IMSoP, The question may seem clear to you, but it obviously isn't to the people, who otherwise could provide the answer. Please, edit the question and provide the missing information -- don't waste your 100 rep points.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm not the person asking the question, I'm answering it. The output required is specified in the 3rd sentence: "I want to be able to get to the data from the following two siblings"; it's reasonable to assume that the `echo`s are just for debugging purposes, and the actual code will stash and process these values somewhere once they can be retrieved successfully.

Comment: @IMSoP, "to get to the data" has nothing to do with what must be output.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev most functions in a program don't "output" anything, in the sense of `echo`; they capture data, and pass it to other functions. "get the data" makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @IMSoP, "Getting the data" may mean different things: 1) selecting the following two siblings elements; 2) Selecting the following two siblings nodes; 3). Selecting the following two siblings' text nodes children; 4) Producing the string value of each of the following two siblings-XXX where "XXX" is a node of type described in 1) to 3) above, ..., etc, ... As for the default namespace not being important, here you are making a bifg mistake. Nearly every second XPath question is asking how to select elements (or why no elements are actually selected) with/by an XPath expression.

Comment: @IMSoP, Due to this reason, I cannot afford to invest time in providing a solution to a problem, only to learn after that that the real issue is just the default namespace. This *needs* to be clarified before starting to solve the problem.

Comment: Non-answer: that looks like an MS Office Open XML file.  [There's a PHP library designed *just* to read the Open XML Excel file format](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).  You might have a better experience using that tool than processing the XML manually to extract the data.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev As per my answer below, the reason the XPath didn't work had nothing to do with either namespaces nor limitations of SimpleXML's XPath integration, but an incorrect reading of which nodes were "siblings" to which others. Running the XPath from the question on the Cell rather than the Data node works fine. Regards your different interpretations of "getting the data", they all seem pretty equivalent to me, particularly since the word "data" implies reading out from the document, not traversing it for manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason asking for siblings isn't working is that the `<Data>` elements aren't siblings; they're more like cousins - children of adjacent `<Cell>` elements.

For the same reason, you shouldn't be using `foreach($row->Cell->Data as $data)`, as this is equivalent to `foreach($row->Cell[0]->Data as $data)`, i.e. look at all `<Data>` children of the first `<Cell>` node. Since there will only ever be one `<Data>` element in a `<Cell>`, you might as well just write `$data = $row->Cell[0]->Data` - which in this case is fine, because the values you're looking for are at the beginning of rows.

What you actually need to do is loop over the `<Cell>`s: `foreach($row->Cell as $cell) { $data = $cell->Data; /* ... */ }`

You then have a couple of options for finding the adjacent cells, including XPath. A more "PHP-ish" way would be to use array indexes (siblings are indexed numerically in SimpleXML loop/array access):

```
foreach($row->Cell as $cell_index => $cell)
{
    $data = $cell->Data;
    if ($data == $ids[$i])
    {
        // Tip: always cast SimpleXML objects to string when you're done with their magic XMLiness
        $latitudes[$i] = (string)$row->Cell[ $cell_index + 1 ]->Data;
        $longitudes[$i] = (string)$row->Cell[ $cell_index + 2 ]->Data;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could rely on your IDs always being in the first column, and the lat and long in the next two (this is a spreadsheet, after all!) and avoid the inner loop altogether:

```
if ( $row->Cell[0]->Data == $ids[$i] )
{
    $latitudes[$i] = (string)$row->Cell[1]->Data;
    $longitudes[$i] = (string)$row->Cell[2]->Data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I know understand the problem with my code. I have implemented your code (tried both "versions"), but there's one problem that I wonder how to solve, and that's the iteration through the id's inside $ids. I tried put the code inside a for loop which means I iterate through all the Cell nodes for every $row as many times there's data left to iterate through in $ids. That works, but takes to long (over 60s so that the PHP parser shows an error message). How could this be done in a better, faster way?

Comment: @holyredbeard definitely you'll achieve some speedup on changing `for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)` into `for ($i = 0, $c = count($ids); $i < $c; $i++)` from your question code (in case of `$i < count($ids)` count is executed on every iteration). 
This example assumes that lat and lng are `$cell_index + 1` and `$cell_index + 2` - so at first check how many cells is in and if there is no more than 3 or no more than 2 left to process (except  one currently processed) then break and go to another row.

Comment: sorry, I meant if there is less than 3 overall or less than 2 except current one

Comment: @holyredbeard as mentioned in one of the other answers, you could use `in_array`, or `array_search`. You could also switch the loops around, so inside each row, you check for each ID in turn. If the IDs are unique, you could remove them from the list when you find them; once you have none left, you can use `break` to stop looking (use e.g. `break 3` if you end up with 3 nested loops).

Comment: @holyredbeard See also my additional answer, which should be more efficient if there are lots of IDs to search for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in case of this XML, cells are always in same order so it can be done as follows:

```
$ids = array('8', '53', '38');
foreach ($xml->Worksheet->Table->Row as $row) {
    $children = $row->children();
    if (count($children) == 3 && in_array(((string) $children[0]->Data), $ids)) {
        echo 'lat: ' . $children[1]->Data . ' lng: ' . $children[2]->Data . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it entirely in XPath, without any loops, like:

```
//Row[Cell/Data[. = '8' or . = '53' or . = '38']]/following-sibling::*[position() <= 2]
```

That search all rows with the id in any data element and then takes the next two siblings.

Or

```
//Row[Cell[1]/Data[. = '8' or . = '53' or . = '38']]/following-sibling::*[position() <= 2]
```

if it is sure that the id is always in the first cell. (which also prevents errors due to an id being the same as a longitude/langitude)

Or

```
//Row[Cell[@ss:Index = "2"]/Data[. = '8' or . = '53' or . = '38']]/following-sibling::*[position() <= 2]
```

if the id is in the cell with index 2.

But in all cases, you need to initialize the namespaces correctly

Comment: Interesting approach. I have a couple of questions though. 1. In your code you're explicitly looking for id's 8, 53 and 38, but it can be any id (1 or many) inside $ids. Could I put the variable directly inside the XPath code? 2. I want to save the id with it's positions in a multidimensional array, how could that be done with your code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1: In XPath 2 you could, I don't know if you can do that directly in XPath 1. But you can construct the query dynamically  `". = '".implode("' or . = '",$ids)."'"`            2: XPath does not support multidimensional arrays. You could remove the following- siblings from the query to get all the matching rows, and then get their next siblings in php with the dom functions

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach if you have lots of IDs to match is to create a "hash" of all the rows based on their ID, and then look into that hash rather than looping through searching for matches.

```
// Initialise an empty array to use as the hash
$rows_by_id = array();

// Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet
foreach ($thePositions->Worksheet->Table->Row as $row) {
    // Skip rows with less than 3 cells
    if ( count($row->Cell) < 3 ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Take the ID from the first cell on the row
    $id = (string)$row->Cell[0]->Data;

    // Add this row to the hash, identified by it's ID
    $rows_by_id[$id] = array(
        'latitude'  => (string)$row->Cell[1]->Data,
        'longitude' => (string)$row->Cell[2]->Data
    );

    // Or if your IDs are not unique, and you want all matches:
    // $rows_by_id[$id][] = array( ... )
}

foreach ( $ids  as $required_id ) {
    // Retrieve the results from the hash
    if ( isset($rows_by_id[$required_id]) ) { 
        $matched_row = $rows_by_id[$required_id];

        echo "ID $required_id has latitude {$matched_row['latitude']} and longitude {$matched_row['longitude']}.\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "ID $required_id was not matched. :(\n";
    }

    // If you have non-unique matches, you'll need something like this:
    // $all_matched_rows = $rows_by_id[$required_id]; ... foreach ( $all_matched_rows as $matched_row )
}
```

Comment: you'll get notice when there is no row for `$required_id` - you should check if it exists (`$matched_row =  isset($rows_by_id[$required_id]) ? $_rows_by_id[$required_id] : null;`)

Comment: @lupatus Good point. I tend to run with notices turned off, because I find that fixing them all would actually lead to uglier code for little benefit. In this case `if ( isset($rows_by_id[$required_id]) ) { $matched_row = $rows_by_id[$required_id]; ... }` would probably make sense.

Comment: (answer edited to incorporate an `isset` and row-width check)